# UIWebView webViewDidStartLoad is called with request which properties are null

Tags: iphone, performance, uiwebview

I am currently debugging a UIWebView in order to get some information to improve performance (on server and iPhone). 
I noticed that after calling loadRequest: the callback

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView_
```

is called, however each parameter of the request is null.

I am using the following statement:

```
    - (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView_{
    NSLog(@"%@ \t Start Request: %@ \n absolute: %@ \n Method: %@ \n Parameters: %@ \n Port: %@ \n Query: %@ \n Header Fields: %@ \n HTTPBody: %@ \n HTTPBodyStream: %@", [NSDate date], [[webView_ request] mainDocumentURL], [[[webView_ request] mainDocumentURL] absoluteString], [[webView_ request] HTTPMethod], [[[webView_ request] mainDocumentURL] parameterString], [[[webView_ request] mainDocumentURL] port], [[[webView_ request] mainDocumentURL] query], [[webView_ request] allHTTPHeaderFields], [[webView_ request] HTTPBody], [[webView_ request] HTTPBodyStream]);
}
```

The output is:

```
 2011-05-11 17:15:34 +0200    Start Request: (null) 
 absolute: (null) 
 Method: GET 
 Parameters: (null) 
 Port: (null) 
 Query: (null) 
 Header Fields: {
} 
 HTTPBody: (null) 
 HTTPBodyStream: (null)
```

Is there any explanation for this behavior or anything to fix this?

The page loads fine, however the request loading nothing seems to take about 30 seconds which I try to avoid.

edit: some additional information about loading the webview. I am calling a method which adds the webview to the UIView and loads the URL

```
    UIWebView * web = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(indent, topindent+indent, screenSize.width-2*indent, screenSize.height-2*indent-topindent)];
     web.delegate = self;
    [view addSubview:web];
    NSURLRequest * someUrl = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:
@"some_URL"]];
    [web loadRequest: someUrl];
```

Comment: I see the exact same behavior, not sure what to make of it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're not seeing a request is that the request property of the webview isn't assigned until the request has been loaded.  This is likely to only show the actual displayed request, after all redirects.  If you want the initial request object, before redirects etc, use ToddH's answer.  For the final request, you will have to check it in webViewDidFinishLoad.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after struggling with this same issue I discovered that the solution is to use this UIWebViewDelegate method:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

It gets called right before viewDidStartLoad and is passed the request object that the view will load with.

Comment: I used that callback to track which URL is being called. However,  I found that it didn't give accurate information about the time to load a request and about the order.

Comment: Use this function and if you return YES then method didStartLoading will be called.

Answer (score 0):

The one thing you didn't check is the request URL property.  Check that, and see what you get:

```
[[[webView_ request] URL] absoluteString]
```

Edit:

It looks like you might be having problems with autoreleased objects.  Try creating the NSURL separate fromt he NSURLRequest:

```
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithSTring:@"some_URL"];
NSURLRequest *someUrl = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];
[web loadRequest:someUrl];
```

Comment: true, unfortunately doesn't provide any usable information - just an empty string: Start Request: (null) 
 URL:  
 Method: GET 
 Parameters: (null) 
 Port: (null) 
 Query: (null) 
 Header Fields: {
}

Comment: Hmm, what are you trying to get, and when is this being called?  How are you loading the request into the Webview

Comment: I added the information about loading the request to the initial question

Comment: unfortunately didn't change anything

Comment: try also overloading the webview:shouldStartLoadWithRequest: method of the delegate and see what you get from the request there

Comment: I'm pretty sure your URL format is wrong. Check console for any hints when instantiating NSURLRequest/NSURL

Comment: shouldStartLoadWithRequest returns a valid URL, it's only webViewDidStartLoad that returns null. There are no hints in the console about a wrong formatted url etc. The Url also works fine in a browser, so I don't think that is the case.